# Please help identify plaster wall texture pattern/technique

Tags: plaster

[image]

I’m hoping to get some advice on how to match a plaster wall texture in a home built in the 1930s. I thought it was a “slap brush” or “crow’s foot” texture, but my attempts to replicate it end up looking nothing like the existing texture. Does anyone have advice on what it’s called and how to replicate it?

Comment: I didn't realise that they had universal names.  My neighbour used to do these in the 80s and he used anything at all to create them - such as mops, and brooms of different types.  If you are working on these walls, then you should perhaps get it tested for asbestos.

Comment: It may be a lining paper.  Look for pattern repetition to confirm.

Comment: Thx, but I can confirm this isn’t an underlayment. It’s very irregular and in the places where it’s weakened there is no sign of anything underneath giving it this texture

Answer (score 1):

Textures like yours are like "art"  or "signatures" they are unique to the one who applies it.

What is on your wall appears to be something applied with a sea sponge or a rag and done in stages.  My best guess is a sea sponge was used to apply the compound. Then a foam squeegee was lightly wiped over it to smooth down the "peaks".  This technique could still not match because the sponge you may use will have a different print than the original user. The height of the individual peaks will have an effect on the pattern as well.

The idea was to make the pattern "perfectly imperfect" which is almost an impossibility to reproduce exactly.

You can experiment with a sea sponge dipped in drywall compound. Try varying the density of the compound. Wipe with a foam squeegee in varying directions.  Also try different sides of the sponge, possibly tearing it to get new patterns.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I’ll give it a whirl on a practice site. I’m also looking into finding a plaster professional in my area.

Comment: I agree with the sea sponge recommendation. However, I bet that the peaks were removed after letting it dry for a little -- enough to be hard to the touch and not to be deformed when lightly moving a sponge over it, but still soft enough that a wet sponge could work on it without removing the underlying pattern.